# Start a program after waiting for user input

Tags: command-line, windows-8.1, batch-file, cmd.exe

I'm writing a `.bat` file, and I'd like to start a program after waiting for the user to press any key. I tried the command below, but I got and "Invalid syntax" error:

```
timeout /t -1 foo.exe
```

Comment: Wait for user input (press any key) then open a program.

Comment: Then you should probably use something like this: `timeout /t -1 && start "bar" "foo.exe"`

Comment: That's it. I was missing the `&& start foo.exe` Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

The only purpose of the `timeout` command is to wait:

> This utility accepts a timeout parameter to wait for the specified
>   time period (in seconds) or until any key is pressed. It also
>   accepts a parameter to ignore the key press.
>
> <sub>Source: timeout /?</sub>

If you want to start `foo.exe` afterwards, you can use something like this:

```
timeout /t -1 && start "bar" "X:\Path\to\foo.exe"
```

**Note** While you could just concatenate commands by using one ampersand (`&`), a double ampersand will ensure that the second command is executed only if the previous one finished successfully.

### Further reading

- [Batch files - Conditional execution](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php)
- [Command-Line Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx)